# I installed gnome on ubuntu 14.04 and now unity is broken

Tags: unity, gnome, 14.04

How do I fix unity. I installed gnome 14.04 and now the unity shell is broken. I tried reinstalling it. Did not work.

Answer (score 2):

CTRL+ALT+F1

```
$ sudo apt-get autoremove ubuntu-desktop 
$ sudo apt-get autoremove unity 
$ sudo apt-get update 
$ sudo apt-get install unity-2d 
$ sudo apt-get install unity
$ sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop 
$ sudo apt-get dist-upgrade 
$ sudo shutdown -r
```

after the reboot's done CTRL+ALT+F1 again & reset your unity

```
$ setsid unity
```